# Does 耶 still hold any value in Japanese?

Tags: particle-か

While I was flipping through a kanji dictionary (2013's Kodansha KLD), I came across 耶{や} , which in the book, said it was the interrogative particle か. However, after a bit more research, it doesn't seem to yield anything outside of Chinese; is it nowadays no longer used as an interrogative particle, or just not used at all?

Comment: You might want to read what is considered a duplicate question (see particularly the sentence about “the same potential answer”) and how to handle such situations https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/

Comment: This isn't a duplicate-question, however...

Comment: Of course it is not. I am trying to educate you as you had a different opinion on your today’s question which you deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an honest answer, it has little to no value in the modern Japanese-speaking world.

For the vast majority of Japanese-speakers, 「耶{や}​ 」 is just a kanji for that syllable used in some girls' names.

Unless one is a kanji scholar or one just wants to nitpick for the heck of it, 「耶」 has no other use in modern Japanese.

Comment: 固有名詞以外だとあとは「有耶無耶」くらいでしょうか．